# Cannot change administrator rights in Windows 7 - firewall_unable to turn firewall off

Tags: windows-7, permissions, firewall, user-accounts, administrator

My system has Windows 7 Professional ,Service Pack 1, 64bit installed. The problem is Windows Firewall will not recognize me as the administrator. I AM the administrator, and I need to turn it off!

There is only one user on this machine, one user account. Control panel\user accounts shows that I am the administrator:

[image]

This is driving me bonkers. I have googled and searched for 2 or 3 days and gotten nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall policy may be controlled by another program like an anti-virus. In such a case, you cannot make any changes to the firewall ... you must do them from the program controlling it. Such a setup is widely used in companies.